# Custom Keyboard: Hub connection error

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard, ios-app-extension

recently I was playing around with the custom keyboard extension in iOS 8 Beta with Swift (Xcode beta 6), but I keep getting this error when I run it on a simulator, it seems to be quite random and I've no idea what causes it:

> plugin com.name.app.extensionName interrupted
>
> Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.name.app.extensionName) UserInfo=0x7b087720 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.name.app.extensionName}

I have no idea what to do. I can't test the app on a real device at the moment, therefore I'm stuck here. It happens on all types of simulators, I already reset them and restarted Xcode and my computer.

I hope you can give me any advice or maybe even know a fix!

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I am getting a similar error on a Today Extension.

Comment: Not sure if this will help your issue, but changing from using Swift to using Objective-C solved the issue for me.

Comment: Hey there, unfortunately I haven't figured out why this happens, but since the update to the GM Version of Xcode 6 it didn't occur anymore. Maybe it was just a beta bug in Xcode...

Comment: It's still happening for me in the GM, at least for a Today Extension. I submitted a radar for it: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5335084760563712

Comment: Its happening to me too. Xcode 6.0.1 GM. Is this a problem with extension or Xcode?

Comment: I got such an issue when I used my own private framework. Not yet sure what it the issue is but once I included all files directly this problem vanished.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in Today Extension written in Objective-C. After updating to XCode 6.0.1 and building my project it started saying about missing ARM64 Architecture. When added arm64 it started working well. Try to play with it

Comment: this does not solve the problem. arm64 is default in all new ios8 projects

Comment: With my today extension - I use "Clear snapshot" in Widget Simulator menu (at left bottom of the simulator window). This solved my similar problem.

Comment: Another trick is open "Product" menu, hold "Option" key and press "Clean Build Folder..."

Answer (score 1):

I tried a variety of things to resolve this and ultimately what fixed it was "cleaning" my application (on the "Product" menu). I don't know what that really does, but I "cleaned" it, then restarted the simulator and suddenly everything is working again.